# Should the "F" in "Farmer John" be capitalized mid-sentence?

Tags: pronouns, capitalization

I'm writing story-generating software. One specific story involves a farmer with a variable name. I'll use "John" as an example. For a "folksy" or "old-timey" or "child-targeted" sound to the story, I always refer to the character as "Farmer John" instead of just "John."

Starting sentences, it's clear that the "F" in "Farmer John" is capitalized -- but I'm unclear whether the "F" in "Farmer John" should be capitalized mid-sentence as well.

E.g. which of these is correct, and why?

> Martha sees Farmer John building a barn.

> Martha sees farmer John building a barn.

My doubt is because in the context that I'm using "Farmer John", it *feels* as though the entirety of "Farmer John" is a name/pronoun, therefore both words deserving capitalization -- but I can't claim anything other than a gut feeling to legitimize that.

Comment: Yes; I'm fairly sure that 'President X' has been addressed here before (a title needing capitalisation throughout), but 'Farmer X' doesn't seem to carry the same gravitas. However, Tolkien capitalised 'Farmer Giles' consistently.

Comment: As did Hardy with Farmer Oak. The relative prestige of presidents and farmers depends on where you were brought up.

Comment: As well as Brer Rabbit, Friar Tuck, and a whole host of other titles (or pseudo-titles, or whatever you’d like to call them). Capitalizing is common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Martha sees Farmer John building a barn.
2. *Martha sees farmer John building a barn.

To be correct, the second should be

Martha sees **the** farmer, John, building a barn.

You are writing it and have chosen the name of the character as "Farmer John" - as opposed to say, "John Farmer" or "John Smith".

Its a name - it's capitalised.

Comment: The term "proper noun" suddenly popped into memory from the recesses of my brain in which it lay dormant. Is "Farmer John" a _proper noun_ in this context, and is that the reason both words can be treated as a _name_, thus deserving capitalization?

Comment: Yes, an occupational identifier is treated like a name and is therefore a proper noun. AFAIK the children's character Postman Pat is always capitalised.